# Merge Two Objects without Applying Subsurf to Both

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have two objects, one with a *Subdivision surface* object modifier, and one without. However, when I join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, the *Subdivision surface* modifier now affects both objects (not what I want).

Is there a way to join two objects with only the intended object being subject to a *Subdivision surface* object modifier?

Comment: Apply the Subsurf Modifier in Object Mode before you join them.

Comment: It still applies Subsurf Modifier to both when i join them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the mesh with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. In the *Properties panel > Object modifiers tab > Subdivision Surface modifier*, make sure the *View:* and *Render:* values are equal. Click the *Apply* button. The modifier should disappear from the stack. Now select one, then the other, then key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them.

[image]

Comment: Why did i not think of this? Thanks again Puck!

Comment: @Ulus Always glad to help.